# toggleClass animation not working? or need help toggling animation

Tags: jquery, toggle, toggleclass

I am working with this code:

```
 $('#products h2').click(
        function() {
           $('.well').toggleClass('margin-left260', 100000);
            return false;
        }
    );
```

What I want to do is slide a div over 260 using a left margin, and then have it slide back on click to 0.  I don't understand why .toggleClass is not animating for me.

I also did well earlier using .animate(margin-left,'260px); but for the life of me could figure out how to use the toggle to have it return to a margin of 0.  What am I missing here?

Comment: do you have jQuery ui library in the page also can you share the html and css also

Comment: "my css is predictable"? what does that mean?

Comment: what I'm looking for is the html... because it is necessary to recreate the problem

Comment: also are you using twitter bootstrap

Comment: where did you get the idea the second parameter of toggleClass had anything to do with animation?

Comment: This is what I was looking at: http://jqueryui.com/toggleClass/ and here: http://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/  I thought that had to do with the time it took to animate it.

Comment: Ok, so in that example you may need to pass the hide show boolean before the duration. `.toggleClass('margin-left260', true, 100000)` might work. I see in the examples it doesnt look like they require it. Perhaps also passing an ease option. Interesting. Side note, you are including jquery ui, right?

Comment: Oh my God, friends.  Thank you.  It was the jQuery UI.  I haven't used that before.  Now my margins are animating like CRAZY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a jsfiddle example here - http://jsfiddle.net/BaXyR/

basically

```
$('.clickme').click(function(){
if($('#moveme').hasClass('marginleft260')){
      $('#moveme').animate({
        marginLeft: "-=260px",
      }, 5000, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('marginleft260');
      });    
}else{
      $('#moveme').animate({
        marginLeft: "+=260px",
      }, 5000, function() {
        $(this).addClass('marginleft260');
      });    
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

toggleClass can be used to add / remove a class / classes on a toggle.  is margin-left260 a class in your css i.e.

```
.margin-left260 {
    margin-left:260px;
}
```

also looking at your code, i think you are not implementing toggleClass correctly.  see : http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

are you trying to animate the movement?

I think the correct code would be use the animate function - see : http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Yes, it is a class.  It is successfully putting the margin into the left, but not animating it.

Comment: Ok, great.  Animate worked well, but I was having trouble getting the second click to return it to margin-left 0

Comment: I think you need to use the hasClass('margin-left260') in an if statement, and then if so then do the animate the other way.